# How to start celery 5 using django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

I am getting this error when trying to start the celery service.

I figured it would be the version of celery 5.

But I still haven't found a solution.

Thanks for listening friends.

Setting

```
 http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.0.2/userguide/configuration.html
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://:123456@redis:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://:123456@redis:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'


root@b9249c0a5916:/usr/src/app# celery -A sistema worker -l info
Usage: celery worker [OPTIONS]
Try 'celery worker --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value for '-l' / '--loglevel': invalid choice: info. (choose from DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL, FATAL)
root@b9249c0a5916:/usr/src/app#
```

Answer (score 1):

The error seems explicit:

```
Error: Invalid value for '-l' / '--loglevel': invalid choice: info. (choose from DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL, FATAL)
```

Doesn't this work?

```
root@b9249c0a5916:/usr/src/app# celery -A sistema worker -l INFO
```